# How to get IPortableDeviceContent interface for given PIDL

Tags: c++, windows, interface, wpd, mtp

I use SHBrowseForFolder() to select a folder on MTP device. Then I want to copy file from/to there. IPortableDeviceContent interface (from Windows Portable Devices SDK) seems suitable, but how to get it for the object with PIDL, returned from SHBrowseForFolder()?

(I asked similar question about obtaining IWMDMStorageControl interface:
[How to get IWMDMStorageControl interface for given PIDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433978/how-to-get-iwmdmstoragecontrol-interface-for-given-pidl))

Comment: Did you find a way to at least retreive the displayed name associated with the PILD returned by SHBrowseForFolder() for the selected MTP folder ?

Comment: Yes. In this way:
TCHAR DisplayName[MAX_PATH]; // we will get it here
LPITEMIDLIST pidlSelected = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);
if (pidlSelected && !SHGetPathFromIDList(pidlSelected, DisplayName))
{ // it is media device
IShellFolder *psfParent;
LPCITEMIDLIST pidlRelative;
STRRET str;
HRESULT hres = SHBindToParent(pidlSelected, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&psfParent, &pidlRelative);
if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
  {
  psfParent->GetDisplayNameOf(pidlRelative, SHGDN_FORADDRESSBAR, &str);
  psfParent->Release();
  StrRetToBuf(&str, pidlSelected, DisplayName, sizeof(DisplayName)/sizeof(DisplayName[0]));
  }
}

Comment: Sorry about lack of formatting here, I will place the code as regular comment also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the displayed name, associated with the PILD from SHBrowseForFolder() in this way:

```
TCHAR DisplayName[MAX_PATH]; // we will get it here
LPITEMIDLIST pidlSelected = SHBrowseForFolder( &bi );
if ( pidlSelected && ! SHGetPathFromIDList(pidlSelected, DisplayName) )
{ // it is media device
    IShellFolder *psfParent;
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlRelative;
    STRRET str;
    HRESULT hres = SHBindToParent(pidlSelected, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&psfParent, &pidlRelative);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
    {
        psfParent->GetDisplayNameOf( pidlRelative, SHGDN_FORADDRESSBAR, &str );
        psfParent->Release();
        StrRetToBuf( &str, pidlSelected, DisplayName, sizeof(DisplayName)/sizeof(DisplayName[0]) );
    }
}
```

Then we can parse the path and traverse through MTP file structure by the same path. It is not elegant solution, but it is the only one which I found.